# Creating an alias for a two word command like git log?

Tags: bash, alias

Sometimes I have a two word command like `git log` or `apt-get install` that I want to add a default parameter to. For example, most of the time I want to add the `--abbrev-commit` parameter to my `git log`, and the `-y` parameter to `apt-get install`.

```
git log --abbrev-commit
apt-get install --abbrev-commit
```

However, I can't seem to create an alias that involves two word commands:

```
$ alias 'git log'='git log --abbrev-commit'
bash: alias: `git log': invalid alias name
 $ alias git log='git log --abbrev-commit'
bash: alias: git: not found
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying with a shell alias.  That's just not how they work.  The `git` one you can handle with git configuration.  Run:

```
git config --global log.abbrevCommit true
```

or, alternately, edit your `~/.gitconfig` and add:

```
[log]
    abbrevCommit = true
```

If you'd prefer to have per-repository behaviour rather than editing your global config, you can remove the `--global` flag or edit your project's `.git/config` instead of your global configuration.

The `apt-get` one will be harder.  You could write a bash function to do it, though.  Something like (untested):

```
apt-get() {
    if [[ $1 == "install" ]]
    then
        command apt-get -y "$@"
    else
        command apt-get "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Only one thing wrong here -- you need to quote your `$@` uses (as `"$@"`) unless you want them to behave the same way as `$*`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
        cm = commit -am
```

With git config command:

```
git config --global alias.cm "commit -am"
```